# UINavigationBar foregroundColor use Color instead of UIColor

Tags: swift, colors, swiftui, uicolor

How do I use a `Color` instead of a `UIColor` for my navigation bar text?

Example, this works:

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
    ]
}
```

This does not:

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
        .foregroundColor: .red
    ]
}
```

How do I do this properly? `UIColor.red` is much uglier than `Color.red`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
var largeTitleTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]? { get set }
```

As you can see the dictionary is `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]`, this means that `.red` cannot be inferred by the compiler, which is why you have to do, `UIColor.red`.

The `.foregroundColor` works just fine because it is expecting a `NSAttributedString.Key`.

I am afraid to say that you have to be explicit in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

So I just found out `UIColor.systemRed` is the same as `Color.red`...